# Testing Extjs with Selenium

Tags: javascript, extjs, selenium, selenium-ide, selenium-chromedriver

actually I am trying to test an extjs application with selenium. I am using selenium ide for Firefox and javasrcipt based with eclipse on chrome. I read hours and hours to find a solution for my problem but I can`t find a mistake in my code.

The only problem I could think of is that the extjs application is too slow for selenium.

Because the problem is following: I wrote the testcase and used waitforElementPresent then click. The whole testcase works fine if I use selenium ID and set speed to the slowest point. If I increase the speed to maximum or the half, at a random point it did`t click a button. This can happen at the first try or at the last try. The same happens with eclipse and I tried to solve it with a pause that worked but it should also work without it.

Hopefully somebody can help me here.

This is a part of my Code in IDE:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="+++" />
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">Login</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>/login</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
 <td>xpath=(//input[@name='data[User][loginUsername]'])</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>xpath=(//input[@name='data[User][loginUsername]'])</td>
 <td>+++</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
 <td>xpath=(//input[@name='data[User][loginUserpassword]'])</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>xpath=(//input[@name='data[User][loginUserpassword]'])</td>
 <td>+++</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
 <td>xpath=(//button[text()='Login'])</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>xpath=(//button[text()='Login'])</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
 <td>xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'neue Projekte in Ihrer Region (')])</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'neue Projekte in Ihrer Region (')])</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForElementNotPresent</td>
 <td>xpath=(//div[text()='Übertrage Daten ...'])</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
 <td>xpath=(//div[@class='x-grid3-hd-checker'])</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
 <td>xpath=(//button[text()='Logout'])</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>xpath=(//button[text()='Logout'])</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
 <td>xpath=(//button[text()='Login'])</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>pause</td>
 <td>2000</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is a part of my Eclipse code:

```
public void testFirmaanlegen() throws Exception {
    driver.get("+++");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa1");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[User][loginUsername]'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[User][loginUsername]'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[User][loginUsername]'])")).sendKeys("****");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa2");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[User][loginUserpassword]'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[User][loginUserpassword]'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[User][loginUserpassword]'])")).sendKeys("*****");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa3");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Login'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Login'])")).click();

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa4");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Eigene Infos'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000); //musste ich einbauen.
    try{
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Eigene Infos'])")).click();
       }
       catch(Exception e){
        if (checkForSession() == true){
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Eigene Infos'])")).click();
        }
       }

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa5");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//span[text()='Eigene Firma anlegen'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }


    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[text()='Eigene Firma anlegen'])")).click();

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa6");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncompany_searchfield_name1'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncompany_searchfield_name1'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncompany_searchfield_name1'])")).sendKeys("automated Test");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa7");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncontact_searchfield_lastname'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncontact_searchfield_lastname'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncontact_searchfield_lastname'])")).sendKeys("iBau");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa8");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncompany_searchfield_postcode'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncompany_searchfield_postcode'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncompany_searchfield_postcode'])")).sendKeys("48163");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa9");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncompany_searchfield_town'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncompany_searchfield_town'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncompany_searchfield_town'])")).sendKeys("Münster");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa10");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncompany_searchfield_street'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncompany_searchfield_street'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncompany_searchfield_street'])")).sendKeys("Teststreet");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa11");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncompany_searchtype_company'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='owncompany_searchtype_company'])")).click();

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa12");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//button[text()='neue Firma anlegen'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[text()='neue Firma anlegen'])")).click();

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa13");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][title]'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][title]'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][title]'])")).sendKeys("Tester");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa14");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][firstname]'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][firstname]'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][firstname]'])")).sendKeys("This is an");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa15");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][name2]'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][name2]'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][name2]'])")).sendKeys("of");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa16");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][pobox]'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][pobox]'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][pobox]'])")).sendKeys("501");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa17");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][pobox_postcode]'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][pobox_postcode]'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][pobox_postcode]'])")).sendKeys("5674");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa18");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][pobox_town]'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][pobox_town]'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][pobox_town]'])")).sendKeys("jggvf");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa19");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][phone]'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][phone]'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][phone]'])")).sendKeys("034674");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa20");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][mobilephone]'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][mobilephone]'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][mobilephone]'])")).sendKeys("04745151");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa21");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][fax]'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][fax]'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][fax]'])")).sendKeys("0284552");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa22");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][email]'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][email]'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][email]'])")).sendKeys("test@test.de");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa23");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][website]'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][website]'])")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='data[Company][website]'])")).sendKeys("http://www.google.de");

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa24");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Speichern'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Speichern'])")).click();

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa25");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//h1[text()='This is an automated Test'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }


    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa26");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Logout'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Logout'])")).click();

    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= secondsToWait) System.out.println("timeoutfa27");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Login'])"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you stated that tests should work without the pauses, but I have found this isn't the case in the actual implementation. Almost every step of my tests require a Thread.sleep(<2000-5000>) in between steps. I ended up wrapping thread.sleep() in my own class because of this. I am struggling my way through getting Selenium to operate the way I think it should myself.